# separate variables from a string and create new array

Tags: javascript

```
input = "<p>My name is ${name}, my age is ${age}.My profession is ${job}<p>"
```

Output should be as follows

```
[name, age, job]
```

in the above string, I want to separate name, age, job into an array.

Comment: Since you are using template lietral which means name,age,job are already stored in variables, then you can simply do `var array = [name, age, job]`. What is the issue here?

Comment: I want to separate those variable and save to database.Also that is normal string. Not template string.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to match the strings inside `${}` and iterate over the matches, pushing them to an array:

```js
let input = "<p>My name is ${name}, my age is ${age}.My profession is ${job}<p>";

let regex = /\$\{([^}]+)\}/g
let matches = []
while (m = regex.exec(input)) {
  matches.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```